# Is there even any need to use the django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to build a backend which resembled a RESTful architecture, and I came across something called the Django REST Framework, which talked about serialization, response (JSONResponse()) and user authentication to build a Web API. However, all these functions are already available in Django 1.8 (serialization, JSONResponse(), user authentication), so my question is whether there is any need now of using the Django REST Framework or was it made for older Django versions and all the things it does is already available in core Django now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you don't *need* DRF. After all, it's just an app that has been written in Python for Django. This essentially means that you can re-create anything you want.

However, after a certain point, you'll find you're just duplicating DRF and would probably be better off using it if your needs are more complex than returning a simple JSON response.